# How to run mongo command with mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

Hi there :) I'm working on a golang app linked to mongo DB (I use the official driver: `mongo-go`) and here's my problem,I want to execute this function

```
db.rmTickets.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.created=new Date(doc.created)
    doc.updated=new Date(doc.updated)
    doc.deadline=new Date(doc.deadline)
    doc.dateEstimationDelivery=new Date(doc.dateEstimationDelivery)
    doc.dateTransmitDemand=new Date(doc.dateTransmitDemand)
    doc.dateTransmitQuotation=new Date(doc.dateTransmitQuotation)
    doc.dateValidationQuotation=new Date(doc.dateValidationQuotation)
    doc.dateDeliveryCS=new Date(doc.dateDeliveryCS)
    db.rmTickets.save(doc)
})
```

I see on godoc that a `Database.RunCommand()` exists but I'm not sure about how to use it.
If someone can help :)
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Did you already try something, share some code. Do you have a specific issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RunCommand` is to execute a mongo command.  What you intend to do are to find all documents of a collection, make changes, and then replace them.  You need `Find()`, cursor, and `ReplaceOne()`.  Here is a similar code snippet.

```
if cur, err = collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"hometown": bson.M{"$exists": 1}}); err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
var doc bson.M
for cur.Next(ctx) {
    cur.Decode(&doc)
    doc["updated"] = time.Now()
    if result, err = collection.ReplaceOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": doc["_id"]}, doc); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if result.MatchedCount != 1 || result.ModifiedCount != 1 {
        t.Fatal("replace failed, expected 1 but got", result.MatchedCount)
    }
}
```

I have a full example [TestReplaceLoop()](https://github.com/simagix/mongo-go-examples/blob/master/examples/replace_test.go)