How to create users with granular permissions via MongoDB Golang Driver?
I am writing a Golang-based tool which is used for managing users in MongoDB (version 7.0.x). I have a few questions around this whole process.
The user needs to be granted specific roles only to specific databases and the roles can be built-in as well custom. Something like
# config.yaml

user: myuser
permissions:
- db: mydb1
  roles:
  - read
  - customRole1
- db: mydb2
  roles:
  - readWrite
  - customRole2

My understanding of Mongodb user management is that a given user needs to be created within a database. Similarly, roles are also created within a database. Now, the user within that database is assigned roles. For eg, in below snippet, the db field tell MongoDB retrieve the someCustomRole from the customDb (and it does NOT assign the role someCustomRole to the user for accessing the customDb).
///// via mongosh CLI

admin> db.createUser( {user:"myuser", pwd: "pass", roles: []});
{ ok: 1 }

admin> db.grantRolesToUser("myuser", [ "read", {role:"someCustomRole", db: "customDb" ])
{ ok: 1 }

////// via Golang driver

var result bson.D
roleBsonArray := bson.A{"read","readWrite"}
resp := client.Database("helloworld").RunCommand(context.Background(),  bson.D{ {"grantRolesToUser", newuser}, {"roles", roleBsonArray}, }).Decode(&result)
fmt.Println("result: ", result)
fmt.Println("resp", resp )

Question1: Is my above understanding correct?
Question2: How would I create users in admin database but then grant the same user specific roles to a specific list of databases?  (as listed in config.yaml snippet above)

The documentation has a brief example where they create the user & roles within the required database, but if my user needs to have access to 5 databases, does it need to be created 5 times in each of the database?

How do i achieve this in Golang ?



You can create a user in any database. You specify the database in the connection option authenticationDatabase. If a user exists in this database and credentials are correct, the connection will be established and the session will have privileges based on the roles assigned to the user. The roles should be defined in the same database and can grant permissions to the resources within this database only.
To manage users in this database you will need to connect to the database with userAdmin role.
Think about it as a multi-tenant mongodb cluster with 1 database per tenant.
The admin database is a special case. From https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/

A role created in the admin database can include privileges that apply to the admin database, other databases or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the admin database.

So in your command

admin> db.createUser( {user:"myuser", pwd: "pass", roles: []});

creates a user in admin database. You will need to use authenticationDatabase=admin in the connection options, or omit it as it is the default authentication database.
To create a user in customDb you would need to :

admin> use customDb;
customDb> db.createUser( {user:"myuser", pwd: "pass", roles: []});

and then use authenticationDatabase=customDb connection option.
A user created in customDb can have roles from this database only. A user created in admin database can heave roles from any database.
In your command

admin> db.grantRolesToUser("myuser", [ "read", {role:"someCustomRole", db: "customDb" ])

you grant myuser a role someCustomRole defined in customDb. Since the role is defined in non-admin database, it can grant access to resource in customDb only.
Roles defined in admin database can grant access to any resources. From https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/

Except for roles created in the admin database, a role can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.
A role created in the admin database can include privileges that apply to the admin database, other databases or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the admin database.

So for the Question 1 " Is my above understanding correct?" - yes, almost. The correct statement will be

For eg, in below snippet, the db field tell MongoDB retrieve the someCustomRole from the customDb (and it does NOT assign the role someCustomRole to the user for accessing the customDb).

For the Question 2  "How would I create users in admin database but then grant the same user specific roles to a specific list of databases?" - you just did. If you need this user to access 5 different databases - create roles in these databases and assign them to the user.
As for golang - it's the same RunCommand, you just need to execute it in the database where the user was created. In your case it's admin database. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320828/1110423 for an example how to create a user and assign roles in one command.

Regarding the line  "If you need this user to access 5 different databases - create roles in these databases and assign them to the user.",  this makes sense to me when I have custom roles which can be created in each of the 5 DBs. But what about a usecase where I want to assign a built-in role to user(say readWrite) but only for a specific list of databases?   Can you please edit your answer and give me more info on that as well?

@BharathRam Just repeat { role: "readWrite", db: "the specific db" } 5 times for each database. The built-in roles are just what it says - the typical prebuilt roles, they exists in all databases. Everything else equally apply to them - the built-in roles in admin database grant permissions to all databases, the built-in roles in specific database are scoped to that database only. There is no magic there.
